# Less task not found error

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

I recently started using grunt and can't seem to get it working:  I installed grunt-cli using npm and also installed a few grunt modules using npm with no issues.  I'm trying to compile all the bootstrap framework's less files into one css file but keep getting an error saying the less task was not found.  i'm sure everything is where it's supposed to be and I loaded the grunt-contrib-less plugin in the gruntfile.  Any idea where I might be going wrong?

My package.json's contents:

```
{
    "name": "dConference",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "latest",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "latest",
    "jshint-stylish": "latest",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "latest",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "latest",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "latest",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "latest" 
    }
}
```

And my gruntfile.js's contents:

```
//gruntfile specifying all tasks to be performed

module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        //all configuration goes here
        less: {
            build: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: "components/less",
                    src: ["*.less"]
                    dest: "css/main.css"
                }               ]
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-jshint");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-uglify");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-cssmin");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");



};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made Gruntfile.js as following.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        less: {
            build: {
                files: {
                    'css/main.css': 'components/less/bootstrap.less'
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-jshint");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-uglify");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-cssmin");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
};
```

And running "grunt less" on project root folder was successful.
After successful running of "grunt less" command, main.css was generated under css folder.

Project structure is:

grunt-test-project

- components/less

  - mixins folder
  - all other bootstrap less files
- css
- Gruntfile.js
- package.json

Please try it on your side and let me know the result.

Comment: Please post entire Gruntfile.js file here

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I just updated my question with the grunt.js file contents

Comment: the file at the bottom is grunt.js not gruntfile.js

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If not, please post entire Gruntfile.js file

Comment: No still no luck...  i'll update the post with my gruntfile.js now.

Comment: I added my gruntfile.js at the bottom of my post.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Where is it? I can't find full gruntfile.js

Comment: I removed grunt.js so now the only code in my post is gruntfile.js at the bottom and package.json is at the top.  Am I maybe not understanding things correctly?  Is grunt.js and gruntfile.js supposed to be the same file?

Comment: Your package.json seems right. I edited Gruntfile.js a bit and it works now. Please look at my answer again. It was edited. @user2094257

Comment: Would you please check my answer again and let me know if it solved? Thanks. @user2094257

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your effort.  That seems to have solved the issue however I now have another issue.  i'm trying to use grunt-less to merge all of the bootstrap framework's less files into 1 css file but it gives me an error saying variable @allert.js is undefined in components/less...  Any idea how I could approach this problem?  should I try using --force with grunt?

Comment: It's easy. You can do it by replacing 'css/main.css': 'components/less/*.less' with 'css/main.css': 'components/less/bootstrap.less'. Please look at my updated answer. Please note that you have to extract bootstrap less folder contents to project_root/components/less folder. Please let me know after you test again.

Comment: Thanks again for all your effort it's working fine now.

Comment: my issue was soooooooooo much simpler -- `npm i --save-dev grunt-contrib-less` did it for me. DOH!